# How does fetching with Psycopg and rendering with Jinja work?

Tags: python, psycopg2

Recently I was building a simple web blog using Flask and PostgreSQL and I stumbled upon something which seems to me like a weird behavior.

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    conn = get_connection()
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM posts")
    posts = cur.fetchall()
    print(posts, flush=True)
    conn.close()
    return render_template('index.html', posts=posts)
```

In this function I'm trying to get all the entries from my database using Psycopg2. In the [documentation](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.fetchall), there is written that fetchall() method should return the list of tuples:

> Fetch all (remaining) rows of a query result, returning them as a list of tuples. An empty list is returned if there is no more record to fetch.

However, what I'm getting back is a list of lists. The print() function is giving me an output like this:
`[[1, datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 24, 23, 25, 39, 559908, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), 'Hello', 'First post.']]` for this schema:

```
CREATE TABLE posts (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    created TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    title TEXT NOT NULL,
    content TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

Regarding the second part of my question; I don't understand how Jinja handles this iterable when I pass it to the render_template() function. What I particularly mean is the fact, that when it iterates through this data in a for cycle it is able to assess specific attribute by using its name like if it was a Python Dictionary. Let me demonstrate what I mean:

```
    {% for post in posts %}
        <a href="{{ url_for('post', post_id=post['id']) }}">
            <h2>{{ post['title'] }}</h2>
        </a>
        <span class="badge badge-primary">{{ post['created'] }}</span>
        <hr>
    {% endfor %}
```

In these two `{{ post['title'] }}` and `{{ post['created'] }}` blocks it is able to access the data by the name of their attributes in DB, which doesn't make any sense if I pass it just the list of lists.

Can somebody please explain to me what is going on in the background and therefore make my confusion go away?

Thank you.

Comment: Usa a [dict cursor](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#dictionary-like-cursor)

Comment: The code in `get_connection()`  is probably doing `...cursor_factory=DictCursor`.  Where `DictCursor` is: 'A cursor that keeps a list of column name -> index mappings.' See explanation of the cursor subclasses here [Cursors](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#connection-and-cursor-subclasses).

Comment: Oh, I see that. Thank you. I was fixed on an assumption that it returns the native Python object. However, if I try to print the `type(posts)` what I get is `<class 'list'>`. Don't you know why?